# META tag 'content' attribute limitations

Tags: html, meta, w3c

The W3C doesn't specify a limit on `content` attribute length for `META` tags and leaves it to the browsers.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4

I'm looking to understand the limits of the [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) and what can be blocked/whitelisted.

**Anyone know what limits browsers have chosen to implement?**

I'm specifically interested in variations between browsers in high-use:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_tables

(Bear in mind this has nothing to do with SEO practices, search engines, robots, crawlers.)

Comment: _"(Bear in mind this has nothing to do with SEO practices, search engines, robots, crawlers.)"_ - well then what _does_ it have to do with? This question feels kinda academical, rather than having any practical application? Or do you have a specific property and/or purpose in mind, that would require or could benefit from, as long as we don't know any actual limit let's call it a "humongous" amount of meta data? And if not, why start at meta data, and not question first what the limit of an `h1` or `p` element's content might be ...?

Comment: @CBroe I want to know how far I can push the [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) `meta` tag.

Comment: Ah, that gives it some context then ... Although I might question how much sense it'd make to implement that on meta element level over HTTP headers to begin with. Anyway, how about testing it? Maybe make up some settings that would make a test document only violate something "at the very end" - and then set up a reporting URL, and see up to which actual length you get proper reports back ...?

Comment: @CBroe Thats what I will do and I've had some [help](https://twitter.com/saila/status/978361565975142400). Agree on using headers, but in this situation client-side decision will drive nature of CSP